# rfcomm0 freezing using PySerial, BluetoothSocket containing 50% garbage - buffer problems?

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm trying to use pyserial for reading out some bluetooth sensor data via rfcomm0.

Setting up the connection using the linux rfcomm command and its rfcomm.conf is working fine. But after a reading attempt using pyserial the device is freezing after a few seconds (until that poing delivering correct data!) and only useable after a complete device reset. Using direct connection with a FTDI level shifter my code is working fine without problems.

rfcomm.conf:

```
rfcomm0 {
Automatically bind the device at startup
bind no;

device 98:D3:31:70:23:90;

channel 1;
comment "Example Bluetooth device";
}
```

Command being used for setting up the connection

```
# rfcomm -i hci0 connect 0
Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to 98:D3:31:70:23:90 on channel 1
```

Relevant python code snippet (looped heavily with magic algorithms read(1)-ing bytes):

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/rfcomm0')
start_frame = ser.read(1)
(...)
```

Python trace when when deadlocking:

```
serialposix.py(443):         if not self._isOpen: raise portNotOpenError
serialposix.py(444):         read = bytearray()
serialposix.py(445):         while len(read) < size:
serialposix.py(446):             ready,_,_ = select.select([self.fd],[],[], self._timeout)
```

Seems as the linux host bluetooth device is stopped delivering data. When I'm attaching a FTDI directly to the bluetooth sensor it' still sending data.

Why is it doing this?! Do I need to flush some magic bluetooth buffers? I even tried two different bluetooth adapters.

On SF i found this article:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/114171/why-is-dev-rfcomm0-giving-pyserial-problems

But using BluetoothSocket and replacing read(1) with recv(1) only 50% of the received data is correct, rest containing garbage (upper solutions gives me 100%  data but dying after ~5 seconds).

Any suggestions?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nailed that beast down:

The whole thing dies when the rfcomm0 buffer on the host side is empty.

read(1)-ing from empty rfcomm0 buffer = deadlock without comeback

Solution:

- Fine: Looking if there's some data in the buffer- when yes, read it
- Ugly: Use some time.delay() and hope for god that there's some data